# set properties of array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am adding an element to an array by duplicating the first element. Then I am changing only certain properties of the first element [0] - but (for some reason I don't understand) the properties of all elements (eg [1]) not just the changed element are also changed.

The code:

```
$this->product->images[] = $this->product->images[0];
$file = uniqid().'.png';
$this->product->images[0]->file_url = 'images/magick/'.$file;
```

This code also changes $this->product->images[1]->file_url to 'images/magick/'.$file when I only want to change the first ([0]) element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
$this->product->images[] = clone $this->product->images[0];
$file = uniqid().'.png';
$this->product->images[0]->file_url = 'images/magick/'.$file;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the items in `$images` are objects (see [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)). So you have to use:

```
$this->product->images[] = clone $this->product->images[0];
```

But be aware, I don't know the class you're using, so it might be you need a deep clone in some cases, also the cloning could be depend on your object (see [Object Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)).